# Struct Class undefined yet used?

Tags: python, oop

This is a part of code from a tkinter game
Random and tkinter module have been imported.
The questions I have are -

1.
The Struct class has only been initialized but not defined and simply passed yet it is used.

```
def run(rows, cols):
# create the root and the canvas
global canvas
root = Tk()
margin = 5
cellSize = 15
canvasWidth = 2*margin + cols*cellSize
canvasHeight = 2*margin + rows*cellSize+100
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight)
canvas.pack()
# Store canvas in root and in canvas itself for callbacks
root.canvas = canvas.canvas = canvas
# Set up canvas data and call init
class Struct: pass
canvas.data = Struct()
canvas.data.margin = margin
canvas.data.cellSize = cellSize
canvas.data.canvasWidth = canvasWidth
canvas.data.canvasHeight = canvasHeight
canvas.data.rows = rows
canvas.data.cols = cols
canvas.data.canvasWidth = canvasWidth
canvas.data.canvasHeight = canvasHeight
canvas.data.player1Score = 0
canvas.data.player2Score = 0
canvas.data.inGame = False
init()
# set up events
root.bind("<Key>", keyPressed)
timerFired()
# and launch the app
root.mainloop()  # This call BLOCKS (so your program waits until you close the window!)
run(40,40)
```

2.
Also what is happening in this line of code:

```
root.canvas = canvas.canvas = canvas
class Struct: pass
canvas.data = Struct()
```

3. How are the canvas.data._______ being used since no class has been defined?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Struct Class undefined yet used?

You are wrong, the `class Struct` **is defined**.
This line defines a valid object:

```
class Struct: pass
```

**The following two examples are equivalent!**

1. Empty object `Struct` becomes a `canvas` attribute and then extend the object with attributes.

   ```
   margin = 5

   # Define the object
   class Struct: pass

   # Instantiate the object `Struct` 
   # Assign the reference to the object `Struct` to the attribute `.data`
   canvas.data = Struct()

   # Assing the value `margin` to the attribute `.margin` of the object `Struct`
   canvas.data.margin = margin

   # Access the attribute `.margin` in the object `Struct`
   print(canvas.data.margin)
   # >>> 5
   ```
2. Object `Struct` using a predefind `class Struct.__init__`

   ```
   margin = 5

   # Define the object
   class Struct:
       def __init__(self, margin):
           self.margin = margin

   # Instantiate the object `Struct` 
   # Pass the value `margin` to it
   # Assign the reference to the object `Struct` to the attribute `.data`
   canvas.data = Struct(margin)

   # Access the attribute `.margin` in the object `Struct`
   print(canvas.data.margin)
   # >>> 5
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how did we access the attribute '.data' of the canvas?

Comment: @AppleKrumble: **"access the attribute `.data` of the canvas"***: `canvas.data`. Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: No what I meant is 'canvas' is an object of the 'Canvas' class which is a part of the 'Tkinter' module. So 'canvas.data' is an attribute of the object 'canvas' which in turn becomes the object of 'Struct' class?

Comment: @AppleKrumble: Are you asking how would it be possible to add a attribute, here `.data`, to a `tkinter class Canvas` instance object, here `canvas`?

Comment: Yes, kind of , is this what is happening in this case ?

Comment: @AppleKrumble Everything in Python is a object, therefore you can do so.

Comment: Okay , so we can add our own attributes to the objects of built-in classes as well ?

Comment: @AppleKrumble: ***"to the objects of built-in classes as well"***: Yes, the only pitfall, you choose a already used attribut name. A common use case [way-of-avoiding-unwanted-garbage-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788728/in-tkinter-is-this-a-good-way-of-avoiding-unwanted-garbage-collection)