# Button image doesn't appear, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently having a problem while trying to assign images to buttons in a for loop:

```
for index in range(16):
        b = tk.Button(button_frame, text = letter,image = tk.PhotoImage(file = letter+".png"),
                      command= self.letter_typed(letter, word_label))

        b.image = tk.PhotoImage(file = letter+".png")
        b.grid(row = index//4, column = index%4)
```

where letter is a letter (string) of the alphabet. I have 26 png each one for a letter of the alphabet, in this function I create only 16 buttons with letters pictures.
Problem is that the picture doesn't appear, only a blank case that has the same size as the picture wanted. I know this has something to do with python garbage collector.
Another thing, I can obtain the result wanted but I need to create manually each PhotoImage instance, and I would like to avoid that if possible, also I should mention that I'm doing all of this **in a class**. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try this approach: [way-of-avoiding-unwanted-garbage-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788728/in-tkinter-is-this-a-good-way-of-avoiding-unwanted-garbage-collection/58791160#58791160)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not save the reference of `tk.PhotoImage` used in `b = tk.Button(...)`.  Also you assigned the result of `self.letter_typed(...)` to `command` argument of `tk.Button`.

Fixed code:

```
for index in range(16):
    tkimg = tk.PhotoImage(file=letter+'.png')
    b = tk.Button(button_frame, text=letter, image=tkimg,
                  command=lambda: self.letter_typed(letter, word_label))
    b.image = tkimg
    b.grid(row=index//4, column=index%4)
```