# button background showing up but no image and its not functional

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, python-imaging-library

Creating the Template Class
I'm using tkinter, tkinter.ttk, pip, PIL, os, sys, and urllib.request

```
class Template:

  def __init__(self,version):
    self.version = version
    templateList.append(self)
    templateVersion.append(version)  

def selectVersion():

  for s in templateList:
    if s.version == selectedVersion.get():
      version.set(s.version)

  for s in templateList:
    if selectedVersion.get() == ("c400"):
```

Buttons being Created assigning images to them and giving them a command.

```
      img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("clearButton.jpg"))
      clear = tk.Button(frame,padx = (-5), pady = (-5),bg = "#616570", image = img,command = lambda: (monHours.delete(0, 'end'))
      clear.grid(column = 0,row = 20)

      runImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("runButton.png"))
      run = tk.Button(frame,image = runImg,bg = "#616570", command = runPy)
      run.grid(column = 4,row = 20)
```

[image: This is a screen shot of the GUI where the buttons should be.]

Comment: is the code that uses the image inside a function?

Comment: Read [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424553/7414759) and [way of avoiding unwanted garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58791160/7414759)

Comment: Thank you stovfl That helped me a lot.